# Do I need a passport/visa to travel inside EU with a change of airplane in Istanbul?

Tags: visas, turkey, eu, amsterdam

I am travelling to Amsterdam from Greece with a change of airplane in Istanbul, is my id enough to travel or do I need a visa/passport? I have already search online and I think it's okay, but I want to make sure I won't have any trouble.

Comment: Although not an actual duplicate, the top answer on https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/146771/my-passport-was-stamped-with-an-exit-stamp-while-transiting-to-another-schengen/146782#146782 will explain why you DO need a passport - not just for Istanbul, but to leave Amsterdam

Comment: Greek citizens can enter Turkey with their national ID (police identity card).

Answer (score 7):

This would depend on your nationality.

If remaining in the “international” transit area you [do not need a visa](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/frequently-asked-questions.en.mfa).

National identity cards issued by [*some* European countries](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/countries-whose-citizens-are-allowed-to-enter-turkey-with-their-national-id_s.en.mfa) can be used to enter Turkey. If your ID card is good enough to visit Turkey it is also enough for airport transfer.

If your nationality is not listed you should bring a passport. Your ID card may not be recognised by Turkey as a travel document. Not having to go through passport control does not mean that you are exempt from having a valid travel document.

Answer (score 2):

[This is a goverment level official page](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/countries-whose-citizens-are-allowed-to-enter-turkey-with-their-national-id_s.en.mfa) of nationalities who can visit Turkey without a visa or with an expired passpord.

Also I am pasting the content of the page in case the page is gone or become unreachable somehow

> Countries whose citizens are allowed to enter Turkey with their
>   national ID’s
>
> 1. Germany
> 2. Belgium
> 3. France
> 4. Georgia
> 5. The Netherlands
> 6. Spain
> 7. Switzerland
> 8. Italy
> 9. Turkish Republic of Northern Cyprus
> 10. Liechtenstein
> 11. Luxemburg
> 12. Malta
> 13. Portugal
> 14. Ukraine
> 15. Greece
>
> Countries whose citizens are allowed to enter Turkey with their
>   expired passports
>
> 1. Germany – Passports expired within the last year / ID’s expired within the last year
> 2. Belgium - Passports expired within the last 5 years.
> 3. France - Passports expired within the last 5 years.
> 4. Spain - Passports expired within the last 5 years.
> 5. Switzerland - Passports expired within the last 5 years.
> 6. Luxemburg - Passports expired within the last 5 years.
> 7. Portugal - Passports expired within the last 5 years.
> 8. Bulgaria – Valid ordinary passport

**Note:** Above information is provided on 26/11/2019. THis informaton may change by time.